# Netsuite customer statement divided per billing addresses

Tags: netsuite

We are trying to customize the Netsuite Customer Statement in order to have for one customer with multiple billing addresses one page per billing address, but not sure if this is really possible. Does anyone knows how to do this?
Many thanks

Comment: Yep, this is completely doable, using SuiteScript.  I've done something similar, based on item types, instead of addresses.  I would suggest editing your question to show what you have tried, what has not worked, and what has worked.

Comment: If you're using the Advanced PDF/HTML Templates, you should even be able to do it completely with the Freemarker markup in the template without resorting to SuiteScript.  Not saying that would be better, but it may fit in more easily with an existing process flow.  But again, show us what you've tried already and where you're stuck.